# Copy first few strings separated by a symbol in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string consist of integer numbers followed by "|" followed by some binary data.

Example.

```
321654|<some binary data here>
```

How do i get the numbers in front of the string in the lowest resource usage possible?

i did get the index of the symbol,

```
string s = "321654654|llasdkjjkwerklsdmv"
int d = s.IndexOf("|");
string n = s.Substring(d + 1).Trim();//did try other trim but unsuccessful
```

What to do next? Tried copyto but copyto only support char[].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you only want the numbers before the pipe, you can do:

```
string n = s.Substring(0, d);
```

(Make it `d + 1` if you want the pipe character to also be included.)

I might be wrong, but I think you are under the impression that the parameter to `string.Substring(int)` represents "length." It does not; it represents the "start-index" of the desired substring, taken up to the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

s.Substring(0,d);

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388%28VS.80%29.aspx) here is a reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388%28VS.80%29.aspx

```
string n = (s.Split("|"))[0]  //this gets you the numbers
string o = (s.Split("|"))[1] //this gets you the letters
```